# Trophy floating in space

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, community-wiki, collectives

On [this answer to "Why does GCC allocate more stack memory than needed?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70965535/7509065), there's a trophy icon (that's supposed to be immediately to the right of usernames) just floating in space: [image: It appears to the left of the username, underneath the edit link.]

My guess is that the triggering condition for this bug is any time a user with a collective trophy was the last one to edit a community wiki answer on a question with one of said collective's tags.

Comment: SO has achieved space flight and received an award for it.

Comment: @VLAZ, let me change that: SO has achieved to create a bug that flies trophies to crazy locations

Comment: Well, I for one am glad this problem exists. Because otherwise I would have probably never got to enjoy reading that rather excellent question/answer pair. But on-topic: if you inspect the content there is also an empty gravatar div next to the trophy icon. So yeah it does look like whatever logic makes the user information under the "edited" text invisible is forgetting a couple of elements :)

Comment: > SO has achieved space flight and received an award for it. 

Now I really wonder whether we should consider fixing it. Maybe this is a feature, not a bug...

Anyway, we'll have a look and fix it. We'll update this post whenever it's done.

Comment: @JD-Stack don't fix it.... It is just a small bug in space.

The days that it took to find this bug really shows why 'bugs' are named 'bugs'

Comment: That's been my observation, too.  Collective trophy + community-wiki edit = floating trophy.  And it's not just me, other users with collective trophies produce the same effect,   e.g. [Different Benchmark results for functions with same early return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72884848)

Comment: This issue has been fixed

Comment: @Berthold Is that worth saying in an answer so I can mark this as accepted?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue has been fixed, and trophies obey the laws of gravity once again.

Comment: Does that mean that if I read Stack Overflow lying in bed with a phone over my head, the trophy is going to fall on me?